# bootstrap drop down button aligns on the wrong side

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When you click on the dropdown ul, the list items (`<li>`) are shown all the way to the left..
As you can see in my simplified jfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3bfvvkbh/

```
<div> 

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">random button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">random button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">random button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Action</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="d``ropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>

    </button>
    <ul id="yearlist" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li> <a>2010</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
var append = function( txt ) {
$("#yearlist").append( '<li>' + txt + '</li>' );
};
append("<a>2012</a>");
append("<a>2014</a>"); 
});
});
```

Comment: btw: I think it has something to to with the btn-group!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this Class [dropdown-menu-right](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_dropdowns.asp) in the UL tag, `class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"`, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bfvvkbh/5/)

```
<ul id="yearlist" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
    <li> <a>2010</a>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The dropdown has be in a seperate btn-group.

See my updated fiddle and also the [Bootstrap Docs - #Nested Button groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-nested)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var append = function (txt) {
            $("#yearlist").append('<li>' + txt + '</li>');
        };
        append("<a>2012</a>");
        append("<a>2014</a>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">random button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">random button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">random button</button>
        <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Action</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>

        </button>
        <ul id="yearlist" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li> <a>2010</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can't see a link to fiddle!
Running the code snippet doen't work either

Comment: fixed it. some issues with libraries

Comment: Good example with CodeSnippet!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the button tag like you're using in the example rather use a div with a `.btn-group` class.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Dropdown</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3bfvvkbh/2/

Answer (score -1):

Everything else is perfect but you just missed to take one extra btn-group to bind button and toggling menu

See: http://jsfiddle.net/3bfvvkbh/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var append = function (txt) {
            $("#yearlist").append('<li>' + txt + '</li>');
        };
        append("<a>2012</a>");
        append("<a>2014</a>");
    });
});
```